# android multiple alarm setting

Tags: android

I want to set a multiple alarm in android. please help me in achieving this task.

Thanks &Regards
Pawan Pathak

Comment: Please don't include e-mail contact details in posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89965/what-to-do-when-questioner-posts-email-address-for-responses

Comment: I want to know is there any code snippet for multiple alarm ...i am sucessfully implemened single alarm but when i trying for muliple using calender no one is setting in application so plz shae me if there is any code available for multiple alarm

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to use multiple intents.
In this example I set 2 alarms, one after 10 seconds and another one after 15 seconds.
Hope it helps.

```
 // set first alarm
Calendar time1 = Calendar.getInstance();
time1.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
// set intent to be fired
PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// set alarm manager
AlarmManager alarm1 = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time1.getTimeInMillis(), sender1);

// set second alarm
Calendar time2 = Calendar.getInstance();
time2.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
// set intent to be fired
PendingIntent sender2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// set alarm manager
AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time2.getTimeInMillis(), sender2);
```